# Why does distinct-values not yield distinct values on a non-atomized sequence

Tags: xpath, distinct-values

Why does

```
(<benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170301</benefitEndDate>,
<benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170501</benefitEndDate>)/distinct-values(.)
```

yield 20170101 20170301 20170101 20170501 (i.e duplicates not eliminated)

but applying it to an atomized version of the sequence

`distinct-values((20170701,20170301,20170701,20170501))` yields

20170701 20170301 20170501

Comment: I know that a solution is to atomize the sequence prior to applying distinct-values. My question is why I have to do that in the first place.

Comment: => nothing to do with atomization, you are not passing a sequence to distinct-values(.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(
  <benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170301</benefitEndDate>,
  <benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170501</benefitEndDate>
)/distinct-values(.)
```

is not the same as:

```
distinct-values(
  <benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170301</benefitEndDate>,
  <benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170501</benefitEndDate>
)
```

The latter returns the distinct-values for a sequence of elements.

Your code returns the distinct-values for each of these elements, it is like calling:

```
(
  distinct-values(<benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>),
  distinct-values(<benefitEndDate>20170301</benefitEndDate>),
  distinct-values(<benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>),
  distinct-values(<benefitEndDate>20170501</benefitEndDate>)
)
```

Another variant, that returns the result you expected is:

```
(
  <benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170301</benefitEndDate>,
  <benefitStartDate>20170101</benefitStartDate>,<benefitEndDate>20170501</benefitEndDate>
) => distinct-values()
```

Best

Michael